# Typo3 8 Backend exception raising on start

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I got the following error message right after login in in backend

[image]

what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: did you click on "online"? what was that link?

Comment: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1425389240 thats the link .. but does not really helps me

Comment: which http server & version & typo3 version? which vhost configuration? you're giving us nothing but a screenshot of an error and expect us to look into the glass bowl to find out the solution.

Comment: I'm running tyo3 8 (Imported a typo3 6 database for migration) ... 

Its a apache Server with php 7.0.X

Comment: vhost is default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default behaviour on errors in the BE:
try the install tool and check for errors.

Errors in configuration where the install tool has checked your installation.
and your apache log to see the exact error. (You see an processed error message).

the error message gives a hint what to look for: `/main`
where have you used it? and does that folder/file exist?
maybe a misunderstanding as you might assume the folder based in web root (something like `/srv/web/html/`) but from the name it is based in disk root (`/`)

have you used it in a configuration (e.g. `LocalConfiguration.php`)?
or in a file-storage record?